# How to call enableEdgeToEdge function inside composables for change status color for specific screen in jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

After the deprecation of **System UI Controller**, how can we change the status bar and navigation bar color for a specific screen? Google introduced a new enableEdgeToEdge. But it only calls inside activity, not inside compostable functions. Assume that we use multiple screens with multiple nested nav graphs with only one activity in the app. With System Ui Controller we can change for a specific screen like:

```
  val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
            systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        )
```

How can I directly change with enableEdgeToEdge? I'm using compose navigation graph and using only one activity in my whole app with multiple nested nav graphs.

Comment: use ```androidx.activity:activity:1.8.2``` latest version and add ```enableEdgeToEdge()``` function in ```MainActivity

Comment: @ChiragThummar I think you didn't get my question. this enableEdgeToEdge() can call only inside MainActivity. But assume I have multiple screens or composables that use multiple nested graphs, how can I use this inside that screen?

Comment: When you add in MainActivity you don't need to place it anywhere

Comment: @ChiragThummar Then what if i want to change status bar color of a specific screen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current activity. Use this method:

```
internal tailrec fun Context.findActivity(): ComponentActivity? =
    when (this) {
        is ComponentActivity -> this
        is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
        else -> null
    }
```

And then set the colors:

```
context.findActivity()?.enableEdgeToEdge()
```